# General source as a degree of freedom of E.O.M. : Should I impose it to be 0?

Tags: general-relativity, action

After some calculations for calculating the determinant of the d'Alembert operator in curved space-time, I came across the following action:
\begin{equation}
S=\int d^4x\,\sqrt{-g} \left[ \frac{1}{72}R^2-\frac{1}{180}R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{180}R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} \right]
\end{equation}
Where $R$ is the Ricci scalar, $R_{\mu\nu}$ the Ricci tensor and $R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ the Riemann tensor. For some purpose, I need to calculate the equation of motion of this action, I've found this:
\begin{equation}
0=\frac{1}{80}\left( 2\nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu R-2g_{\mu\nu} \square R-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu} R^2+2RR_{\mu\nu} \right)+\frac{1}{240}\left( -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu}R_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}R^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}+2R_{\mu \alpha\beta\gamma}R_\nu^{\ \ \alpha\beta\gamma} -4\square R_{\mu\nu}+2\nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu R-4R_{\mu \alpha}R_\nu^{\ \ \alpha}+4R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\alpha\mu\beta\nu}\right)
\end{equation}
Then, after the usual procedure for the linearization of the equations in general relativity (taking a small perturbation $h_{\mu \nu}$ of the Minkowski metric, using the trace-conjugate $\overline{h}_{\mu \nu}$ of $h_{\mu \nu}$, and imposing the Lorenz gauge) I reduced this equation to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\square\square h_{\mu \nu}+\frac{3}{4}\eta_{\mu\nu}\square\square h-\partial_{\mu}\partial_\nu \square h \simeq 0
\end{equation}
Multiplying by $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ we have $\square\square h\simeq 0$. Then, injecting this into the previous equation leads to:
\begin{equation}
\square \left(\frac{1}{2}\square h_{\mu \nu}-\partial_{\mu}\partial_\nu h \right)\simeq 0
\end{equation}
When taking only the Transverse-Traceless part, the equation finally reduces to $\square\square h_{\mu \nu}^{TT}=0$:
\begin{equation}
\square h^{TT}_{\mu\nu}=A_{\mu\nu}(\omega t-\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})+B_{\mu\nu}(\omega t+\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})
\end{equation}
I know how to use the Green function $\square G=\delta$ to find the general solution of the above equation but I would like to know if there is a physical significance behind the fact that the solution decreases to $0$ at $\infty$. Moreover, does this mean that with this action, the vacuum solution to the equations of motion is generally some kind of perturbation of the metric that decreases at infinity? What about the preferred choice $A_{\mu\nu}=B_{\mu\nu}=0$, should I impose it, like a gauge choice?